# What is the best way to set a count down timer inside RecyclerView without affecting UI in Android?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, countdowntimer

I want to set a count down timer inside each event in recyclerview.

I tried it inside onBindViewHolder. It is working but at the same time it is also affecting the UI.

For example, click events are not working.

Is the any best approach to resolve it?

Comment: If click event is not working you can create an interface between activity to the adapter class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `Observable.interval` from `RxJava`
Here's a util function for countdowntimer

```
public static Observable<Long> countdownTimer(long countdownValue, Observer<Long> observer) {
        if (observer == null) return Observable.just((long) 0);

        //.interval is a cold observable
        // it will emit separately for every observer
        Observable<Long> timerObservale = Observable
                .interval(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .takeWhile(new Predicate<Long>() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean test(Long aLong) throws Exception {
                        return aLong <= countdownValue;
                    }
                })
                .doOnError(Throwable::printStackTrace)
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread());

        timerObservale.subscribe(observer);
        return timerObservale;
    }
```

Here's how you would use it

```
Utils.countdownTimer(60, new Observer<Long>() {
            @Override
            public void onSubscribe(Disposable d) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onNext(Long aLong) {
                //do somethng
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(Throwable e) {
                e.printStackTrace();

            }

            @Override
            public void onComplete() {

            }
        });
```

The utils function emits a long every second for a given period of time